# XML Deserializing with Lists

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I am using webclient to deserialize XML content from a webservice:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SearchArticles), new XmlRootAttribute("search_articles"));
var results = (SearchArticles)serializer.Deserialize(response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result);
```

The xml content is like:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><search_articles><articles hits=\"10134\"><article><id>1763794</id>...
```

My Models look like:

```
public class SearchArticles
{
    [XmlElement("articles")]
    public ArticleHelper articles { get; set; }
}

public class ArticleHelper
{
    [XmlAttribute("hits")]
    public long hits { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("article")]
    public List<Article> articles { get; set; }
}

public class Article
{
    public long id { get; set; }
    public string partner { get; set; }
    public string number { get; set; }
    public long number_is_generated { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public long company_id { get; set; }
}
```

This is working, but how can I avoid having the ArticleHelper ?

Comment: I guess this is about .net but I'm not sure... please add a language tag!

Comment: Can you explain more about your Xml Structure? As far as I can tell, `ArticleHelper` represents the `<Articles>` tag in the xml, which you can't really do without? as the xml has 3 layers if im understanding? the root, the articles node, then the individual articles?

Comment: Yes 3 Layers: search_articles, articles, article. Where articles is just a List (Array) of article

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove ArticleHelper by modifying `SearchArticles` and `Article` as:

```
public class SearchArticles
{
    [XmlArray("articles")]
    [XmlArrayItem("article", Type = typeof(Article))]
    public List<Article> articles { get; set; }
}

public class Article
{
    public long id { get; set; }
    public string partner { get; set; }
    public string number { get; set; }
    public long number_is_generated { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public long company_id { get; set; }
}
```

However, you lose access the hits attribute value.

Comment: It is not about the hits attribute. If I put public class Article{[XmlElement("article")] 
    public List<Article> articles { get; set; }}, it does not find the articles node

Comment: @freakdev Added more detail. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks akton, it was not exactly how you wrote, but helped my to solve this. The solution is: public class SearchArticles
    {
        [XmlArray("articles")]
        [XmlArrayItem("article", Type = typeof(Article))]
        public List<Article> articles { get; set; }
    }

Comment: @freakdev Sorry about the copy and paste error. Answer updated.

Comment: @freakdev - This wont actually get you the `hits` attribute, but maybe you dont care.

Comment: I guess my question would be, what is `hits`?  If it means the number of times an article has been viewed, then I would say the xml format is incorrect and that attribute should be moved do the `article` tag.  Then @akton's answer will be correct.  If it really belongs as an attribute to `articles`, then you have to use what you already came up with.

Comment: @SwDevMan81 Is correct. I am researching but I do not think you can get the value of the `hits` attribute and exclude the `ArticleHelper` class.

Comment: Hits is the number of possible elements, which means if hits is 10, then there are 10 articles. I think then it is correct that hits is an attribute of the articles node.